# Double precision in C - printing 50 significant figures yields inaccurate values

Tags: c, double, division

I'm doing an integration program with Riemann sums for my Calculus class. I've decided to use C when computing my integrals, and I noticed a huge error in my program that derives from this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

double x = 2.0/20.0;
printf("%1.50f \n", x);


return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The program gives me : 0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045410. My question: Why does this happen? And how can I fix this? Or at least round off to ~15 decimal places?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, `"%1.50f"` rounds to 50 decimal places, which would be why you're seeing these innacurate results in the first place...

Comment: Also highly recommended is to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and Chapter 4 - Arithmetic of Volume 2 of Donald Knuth's [The Art of Computer Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Art-Computer-Programming.../dp/0201896842).

Answer (score 7):

The basics of floating-point:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

The answer in your case `0.10` is not exactly representable in binary floating-point. Therefore, it's only accurate to about 16 digits. Yet you are trying to print it out to 50 decimal places.

Comment: That makes sense. So can I round my value to 16 decimal places somehow?

Comment: Change the 50 in `"%1.50f\n"` into a sane number such as `"%.16f\n"`.  That works for the number you've got; you might be better of with `%e` or `%g` format for numbers with much larger or smaller magnitude.

Comment: You can't round the number itself since it's stored in binary. But you can round it when you print it out with `%1.16f`. Note that 16 digits is already slightly more than what `double` can hold - not to mention other round-off errors. So printing 16 digits may still have "noise" in the last digits.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more accurate results that what `double` can offer, then you may want to check out some of the [arbitrary precision libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) that are available.